# css not loaded in django production

Tags: css, django, static, nginx, pinax

here is my baffling problem:
Everything is fine on my Pinax development machine,  but when I moved the files to production, (using nginx webserver + flup) no style sheet is loaded.

I have run

> python manage.py build_static

My project, going to server foo.com,  lives in /www/foo and all my static files are copied

/www/foo/site_media/static

and here are the relevant parts in sttings.py

> PINAX_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(pinax.**file**))
>   PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(**file**))
>
> PINAX_THEME = "default"
>
> DEBUG = False
>
> MEDIA_URL = "/site_media/"
>
> STATIC_ROOT =
>   os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,
>   "site_media", "static")
>
> STATIC_URL = "/site_media/static/"
>
> ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX =
>   posixpath.join(STATIC_URL, "admin/")

In nginx's foo.com I have:

> ```
> location /site_media {
>       autoindex on;
>     root  /www/foo/;
> }
>
> location /static/ {
>    root /www/foo/site_media/static/;
> }
> ```

Each time that I try a different tweak,I restart nginx and fcgi (hopefully) :

> python /www/foo/manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=7718 pidfile=/www/foo/foocom.pid maxspare=2

There is no specific rules in urls.py about static files. Do I need to add something here?

I have tried literally dozens of different combination of paths, but no chance. Really got frustrated and appreciate your clues.

Comment: What happens when you try to load the style sheet directly in the browser? What error do you get?

Comment: Pekka, you are a life saver! Your suggestion sparked the idea that solved the problem. Actually there was a permission problem that gave me 403 error. So I made 'chown -R 777 /site_media' and now everything is fine. Thanks so much my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step, try to load the style sheet URL directly in your browser (open "view source" in the HTML page to get the full URL). Check what error you get - it may be enlightening.